# Application Loader: ERROR ITMS-10001: "Multiple items in this package use the same vendor ID

Tags: xcode, application-loader

I'm attempting to upload an IAP through Application Loader. When I attempt to deliver the IAP, I get the following error:

[image: Error given from Application Loader]

The only piece of info I can find related to the vendor ID is in the iTunes package (not .pkg) file that's created by Application Loader.

If you CTRL+click on the package, and click "Show Package Contents", it will open the file structure. Inside, you'll find the .pkg file along with metadata.xml and machine-local-data.xml.

One of the first keys in metadata.xml is `vendor_id`, which is only in there once.

[image: Screenshot of vendor_id key]

The only relevant change that I can think of since I uploaded my last IAP was upgrading Xcode and El Capitan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running into this issue as well. Turns out it only affects itmsp packages with multiple in-app purchases.

Workaround: submit multiple itmsp packages with a single in-app product in each.

Submitted rdar:
http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4963827485507584

Comment: Thank you! Up to this point, I didn't realize I was resubmitting the other products with each package.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to workaround by deleting the other in app purchase entries from metadata.xml in the package created by Application Loader

Comment: This is great, thanks. I ended up just removing the other products from the In-App Purchases tab in Application Loader. Congratulations on first SO response!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I just deleted the local package, close all windows of Application Loader, Exit it, relaunch it, and next submission was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Vender id is case sensitive in metadata.xml

I manage to fix like vendor_id and Application SKU both are in same case (Capital letter).